# Add transition to dropdown Menu

Tags: css, menu, css-transitions

Heyah, I have a transition for when you click the 'burger icon'(**on mobile screens, max 580px**) and then it becomes an 'x', I would like to also add a transition to the menu that then opens, can anyone help me how I can achieve that?

```
transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
```

Do I use this? and if so where do I put it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#burger-container").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#burger-container").on('click', function() {
    $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open1");
    $("nav").toggleClass("open1");
  });
});
```

```css
/***** BASE STYLES *****/

body{
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

/************************************/

.wrapper{
    max-width: 1180px;
    margin:  0 auto;
}

h1.logo {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 4%;
}

header nav h2{
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-indent: -10000px;
}

#main-banner, #main-banner img{
    width: 100%; 
}

#main-banner img{
    border-top: 2px dashed #a5053d;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #a5053d;
}

p{
    padding: 0 4%;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 170%;
    float: left;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.bigger{
    font-size: 16.25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.paragraph{
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.work img{
    padding-right: 1%;
}

.work p{
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    padding: 0 15%;
    text-align: center;
}

.work{
    text-align: center;
}

#burger{
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

header{
    padding: 0;
}

nav{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
}

nav li{ 
   margin: 10px 20px;
   list-style: none;
}

nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 20px;   
}

a:hover {
    color: #a5053d;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/*************FOOTER************/

.links ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.links ul li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.links ul img {
    margin: 0 4%;
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
}

footer{
    margin-top:  15px;
}

.bottom{
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

li img:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #c1c1c1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #c1c1c1; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #c1c1c1; 
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #c1c1c1; 
  border-radius:100px;
}

/******** BURGER ********/
@media all and (max-width: 580px){

#burger-container{
    margin: 25px 0 0 0;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 70px;
}

#burger{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

#burger span{
    background: black;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

#burger-container.open span:nth-child(2){
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

#burger-container.open span:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: -13px;
}

#burger-container.open span:nth-child(1){
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 13px;
}

}

/***************mobiles*********************/

@media all and (max-width: 580px){
    
nav{
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 45px;
    background-color: #666666;
    height: 0;
}
    
header nav ul{
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
}

header nav ul.open1, nav.open1{
     height: auto;
}
    
header nav ul li{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
}
    
nav li a, nav ul li{
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}

header .wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}   
    
h1.logo {
padding: 0;
margin: 20px;
}
    
header{
    padding: 0;
}

.paragraph{
   padding: 10px 20px 40px 20px;
}           

.work p{
        padding: 0 0 40px 0;
        margin: 0 20px;
}   
.work h3{
    padding: 0 20px;
}  
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/heart.png">
  <title>heartcube</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/burger.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="logo">Heartcube</h1>

      <!-- ............BURGER............ -->

      <div id="burger-container">
        <div id="burger">
          <span>&nbsp;</span>
          <span>&nbsp;</span>
          <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <h2>Main Navigation</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#l">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

  </header>

  <!-- START OF HOMEPAGE CONTENT-->

  <div id="main-banner">
    <img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/img/london.jpg" alt="london banner">
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <section id="home-menu">

      <h2>Betti Bremm</h2>

      <p class="paragraph"><span class="bigger">A little bit about me.</span> I'm a young and motivated Webdesigner located in West London. My journey into tech started when I was quite young already, I always loved setting up websites and my own homepages, but without coding
        it myself. I've always been fascinated with the internet, it's design and social media. I was hooked and wanted to learn how to build my own site to fit my own specific needs. That curiosity then opened a door that could never be shut. When I
        learned how to build my first website, I realized I found something that gave me the freedom &amp versatility I was looking for in my work. Now I've made a full switch to front-end development, where I can use my organization skills and eye for
        detail to write clean, elegant code.</p>

      <div class="work">

        <img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/img/html.png" alt="HTML icon">
        <h3>Hand-Coded HTML</h3>
        <p>My focus is writing clean, well-formatted, semantic HTML5 by hand to make sure that the content is easy to read, easy to collaborate, trouble-shoot and accessible.</p>

        <img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/img/css.png" alt="CSS icon">
        <h3>Well-Organized CSS</h3>
        <p>I pride myself on writing CSS that is easy to read and build on. I focus on keeping my CSS lean and fast to load, and I make it a habit to stay up to date on current best practices.</p>

        <img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/img/pencil.png" alt="Pencil icon">
        <h3>Ease Converting Designs into Code</h3>
        <p>You can trust me to take a designer's PSD and quickly &amp; accurately convert it into a webpage that is pixel-perfect match.</p>

      </div>

    </section>

  </div>

  <!-- ..END OF HOMEPAGE CONTENT-->
  <div class="bottom">
    <footer>
      <div class="wrapper links">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="mailto:betti94@gmx.de"><img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/img/mail.png" alt="Email"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/Icanfindafaith"><img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="http://fantasydesign.tumblr.com/"> <img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/img/tumblr.png" alt="Tumblrn"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/princessofcakes/"><img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/bettina-bremm-472314131"> <img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>

</body>
```

other links of this code : 
[Homepage](http://heartcube.co.uk/)
or on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/everybodysfeelingwonderland/full/OjyRpM/)

Comment: First of all, both your homepage and codepen are susceptible to change, hindering the usefulness of your question for future visitors with a similar issue. So please add a [mcve] in the question itself, using the snippet button (`<>`). Secondly, your question does not show any research effort. There are literally dozens of tutorial examples on how to achieve this, not to speak about the millions of websites who use the technique, patiently waiting for you to inspect their elements. Or... are you requesting free programming services?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Sorry for not including a snippet, I am quite new here, will do that in the future. And no I am not requesting free programming servies. I just tried inlcuding this transition in multiple places in my code, but just can't work it out where it should really go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full list of changes to (and notes on) existing snippet I made in order to enable the animation:

1. You can't animate `transition` from `0` to `auto` or to `100%`. The only library capable of doing it is `velocity.js` but they use a kind of a hack to determine the value they are rendering to before animating. To better understand the underlying problem [read this](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/).
2. The article linked above will also explain why I changed animating `height` to animating `max-height`.
3. The `#burger` element didn't have `height` and `width`, making it difficult to use. (One had to click exactly on the lines of the burger on order to open it).
4. In order to calculate the proper `max-height` of the element, I chose to wrap your menu inside a wrapper (`.animator`) as it simplified the JavaScript needed to calculate the height, when opening.
5. There's no point into making both the container and the contents have `height:0` when closed. You're only over-complicating the animation and making it harder for yourself to understand/debug what's going on. So I removed placing `open1` on children, I only left it on parent.
6. There's no point in having more than one instance of `$(document).ready(){}`. Just place all the code you want to run on that event into one single wrapper.
7. Generally speaking, there are two types of code you want to run when a page loads:
   a. DOM manipulation code - place on `$(document).ready(){}` - runs first
   b. bind to event code - place on `$(window).load(){}` - runs after

   Since this script was a "bind to event" code, I placed it in `$(window).load(){}`.

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMyEqX).

**Note:** If you ask yourself why I didn't include a SO snippet in the answer and used your pen, the main reason is because your SO snippet is incomplete, as you used relative links for the following assets:

- `normalize.css`,
- `main.css`,
- `burger.css`,
- `index.js`

Comment: thanks for all suggestions, that was VERY helpfull, especially the css trick link, I chose the max-height solution. And also was worried about how to make the clickable area of the burger bigger, cheers man.